# Not able to update mongo in bulk using updateone with upsert

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongo

I am facing a problem. I am trying to update if already exists else insert if not present. I am using Bulk API of spring-mongo driver.

```
DBCollection dbCollection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("supcInfo");
        BulkWriteOperation bulkWriteOperation = dbCollection.initializeUnorderedBulkOperation();
BulkUpdateRequestBuilder builder = bulkWriteOperation.find(new BasicDBObject("_id", supcInfo.getSupc())).upsert();
BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject("$set",new BasicDBObject("_id", supcInfo.getSupc()));
         dbObject = dbObject.append("$set",new BasicDBObject("pogId", supcInfo.getPogId()));
         dbObject = dbObject.append("$set",new BasicDBObject("mrp", supcInfo.getMrp()));
         dbObject = dbObject.append("$set",new BasicDBObject("price", supcInfo.getPrice()));
         dbObject = dbObject.append("$set",new BasicDBObject("primarySellerCode", supcInfo.getPrimarySellerCode()));
         dbObject =  dbObject.append("$set",new BasicDBObject("camsEnabled", supcInfo.isCamsEnabled()));
         dbObject =  dbObject.append("$set",new BasicDBObject("availability", supcInfo.getAvailability()));
         dbObject = dbObject.append("$set",new BasicDBObject("updateTs", supcInfo.getUpdateTs()));
builder.updateOne(dbObject);
bulkWriteOperation.execute();
```

But all fields are not getting updated. Can any one tell me reason and replaceOne works fine but It will recreate Index if there are any.

Comment: Can you add an example where it is not working ? Not sure what`convertToDBObjectToUpdate(supcInfo)` is doing. do we even need a bulk write operation when all you are trying to do is only update ?

Comment: I am sorry. It's dbObject. I am trying to update supcinfo which contains 5 to 7 fields but it is updating first and last one only means _id and updateTs.

{
  "supc": "supc15",
  "pogId": 1354619,
  "mrp": 3322323,
  "price": 99232323,
  "primarySellerCode": "",
  "camsEnabled": true,
  "availability": "in stock"
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the bulk write operations here. You can use the regular update and you should be fine.

Your usage of DBObject is incorrect. You are overwriting the $set key.

```
BasicDBObject updateFields = new BasicDBObject("pogId", supcInfo.getPogId()).append("mrp", supcInfo.getMrp()); // Rest of fields.
BasicDBObject dbObject = new BasicDBObject("$set",updateFields);
```

Comment: Thank you. I found where I was making mistake. However I am updating in Bulk because there will be 100 updates per second.